# How to convert ASCII to hexadecimal values in java

Tags: java

How to convert ASCII to hexadecimal values in java.

For example:

> ASCII: 31 32 2E 30 31 33
>
> Hex: 12.013

Comment: @cherouvim: `0x31 == 49`, and ASCII 49 is `'1'`.

Comment: @polygenelubricants: thanks for the deciphering. The question is unclear.

Answer (score 9):

You did not convert ASCII to hexadecimal value. You had `char` values in hexadecimal, and you wanted to convert it to a `String` is how I'm interpreting your question.

```
    String s = new String(new char[] {
        0x31, 0x32, 0x2E, 0x30, 0x31, 0x33
    });
    System.out.println(s); // prints "12.013"
```

If perhaps you're given the string, and you want to print its `char` as hex, then this is how to do it:

```
    for (char ch : "12.013".toCharArray()) {
        System.out.print(Integer.toHexString(ch) + " ");
    } // prints "31 32 2e 30 31 33 "
```

You can also use the `%H` format string:

```
    for (char ch : "12.013".toCharArray()) {
        System.out.format("%H ", ch);
    } // prints "31 32 2E 30 31 33 "
```

Answer (score 4):

It's not entirely clear what you are asking, since your "hex" string is actually in decimal. I believe you are trying to take an ASCII string representing a double and to get its value in the form of a double, in which case using [Double.parseDouble](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#parseDouble%28java.lang.String%29) should be sufficient for your needs. If you need to output a hex string of the double value, then you can use [Double.toHexString](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#toHexString%28double%29). Note you need to catch [NumberFormatException](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/NumberFormatException.html), whenever you invoke one of the primitive wrapper class's parse functions.

```
byte[] ascii = {(byte)0x31, (byte)0x32, (byte)0x2E, (byte)0x30, (byte)0x31, (byte)0x33};
String decimalstr = new String(ascii,"US-ASCII");
double val = Double.parseDouble(decimalstr);
String hexstr = Double.toHexString(val);
```